# How to set up database value in symfony2 select box with data from database

Tags: php, symfony, html-select

How to Selected database value in symfony2 select box (combobox)

my html comobox here.

```
<select name="dashboard_mediabundle_gallerytype[category_id]" id="dashboard_mediabundle_gallerytype_category_id">
    <option value="0">Choose an option</option>
    <option value="1">india</option>
    <option value="2">usa</option>
</select>
```

and  buildform here

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('category_id', 'entity', array(
    'class'         => 'DashboardMediaBundle:category',
    'property' => 'title', 
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
    return $er->createQueryBuilder('mc');
    },
    'label'    => 'Category*:',
    'by_reference' => false,
    'required' => false,
    'empty_value' => 'Choose an option',
    'data' => 2
    ));
}
```

how to set  selected `"<option value="2">usa</option>"`   this value  ?

i have try to   "  'data' => 2  " but not  select `"<option value="2">usa</option>"`

Comment: You want to add an empty value AND set something different as default?

Comment: blank value in display not default value set

Comment: Remove 'empty_value' option.

Comment: hi   Djuro Mandinic 

not set value after Remove 'empty_value' option.